# Unable to save/retrieve data to device using core data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to iOS development and have been learning about core data. I have a modal window to save the data and a UITableView to display it. Here is what I have done with saving the data, I am have no errors but I am not not retrieving any data.

```
let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Name", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)


@IBAction func saveName(sender: AnyObject) {

//Create the managed object to be inserted

    let name = Name(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc!)

    name.title = nameTitle.text
    name.details = nameDetails.text
    name.date = nameDate.date

    var error = NSError?()

    moc?.save(&error)

    //End

    if let problem = error {
            let a = UIAlertView(title: "Sorry..", message: "a problem occurred", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
    } else {
        //DismissWindow
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
    }

 }
```

Here is my fetch request for the table view.

```
@IBOutlet weak var UITable: UITableView!

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var names = [Name]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var error: NSError?

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Name")

    let names = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Name]

    self.UITable.reloadData()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return names.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

        let name = names[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = name.title

        return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for your fetch request or how you are fetching the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not used a `UITableViewController` and instead implemented your own table view. You need to make sure that you also declare that you implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols, otherwise the data will not show.

Also, you prefix your `names` array with the keyword `let` when fetching the data. That transforms it into a local variable in your `viewWillAppear` method. It will be forgotten immediately when this method exits. Instead you want to use your variable `names` that you have declared.

```
self.names = ...
```

Comment: That's great, finally working (Y) I made a school boy error regarding the table datasource, and used self.names to use the variable I had declared.